# Offline api references and recommended online ones?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I want to find an offline good reference on the jsf components.
I'm currently learning about jsf 2.0 from core jsf 2.0 book + glassfish + cdi.

I've found the online version such as
download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/index.html
and 
www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/index.jsf
, but so far i've been unlucky to find the offline versions of the api doc.

Could anyone share offline versions of it, and maybe share other good jsf 2.0 references ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you download Mojarra binaries from their [homepage](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) (click orange button on right hand side), all the necessary documentation is available in `/docs/mojarra-X.X.X-FCS-documentation.zip` of the downloaded binary (where `X.X.X` is the version number). The documentation contains the offline versions of [Java API docs](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/index.html), [JS docs](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/jsdocs/index.html), [Managed bean docs](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/managed-bean-javadocs/index.html), [RenderKit docs](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/renderkitdocs/index.html), [Taglib docs for JSP](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/jsp/index.html) and [Taglib docs for Facelets](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/index.html)). You can also download the [JSF 2.0 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html) PDF file (click the one "for evaluation"), it contains among others also several references about configuration settings.

Comment: Strangely, the current version shown there (2.1.7 as of this writing) is only downloadable as a `jar`, so it comes without documentation.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: Hmm, you'd need the "binary bundle" or "source bundle" downloads: http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html The "bundle" is indeed absent since 2.1.6. Not sure why they changed it like that.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to update this to keep track of things, because I know how difficult it was to get the correct link.

for JSF 2.1.9 ri all jars are at https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.9/